# Dynamic data policy content

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

Please help to understand how to create something like this?

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }

  dynamic "statement" {
    for_each     = var.assume_role_identities != [] ? [true] : []
    content {
      actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
      principals {
        type        = "AWS"
        identifiers = var.assume_role_identities
      }
    }
  }

  dynamic "statement" {
    for_each     = var.assume_role_services != [] ? [true] : []
    content {
      actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
      principals {
        type        = "Service"
        identifiers = var.assume_role_services
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with this code is that if I will not specify any roles or services which should have access, it's an exit with an error that no principals.
Is it possible to set on the dynamic block some count condition? or how to workaround it?

Explanation of problem :

The problem that if I want to pass only some one value, it will not work cause it forming an empty value

This is what terraform apply on this casem if I add only identity records

```
  + assume_role_policy    = jsonencode(
        {
          + Statement = [
              + {
                  + Action    = "sts:AssumeRole"
                  + Effect    = "Allow"
                  + Principal = {
                      + Service = "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                    }
                  + Sid       = ""
                },
              + {
                  + Action    = "sts:AssumeRole"
                  + Effect    = "Allow"
                  + Principal = {
                      + AWS = "arn:aws:iam::account_id:user/some_user"
                    }
                  + Sid       = ""
                },
              + {
                  + Action    = "sts:AssumeRole"
                  + Effect    = "Allow"
                  + Principal = {
                      + Service = []
                    }
                  + Sid       = ""
                },
            ]
          + Version   = "2012-10-17"
        }
    )
```

And from this appearing the problem :

> Error creating IAM Role name-role: MalformedPolicyDocument: Invalid
> principal in policy: com.amazon.balsa.error.InvalidPolicyException:
> The passed in policy has a statement with no principals!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Please could you share your inputs and your expected outputs and then also share what the is currently generating and why that's not what you want? If it errors it would be useful to include the error in your question as well.

Comment: you already have a condition with for_each, no need to have a count. As suggested by @ydaetskcoR, what are your inputs for var.assume_role_identities and var.assume_role_services. Have you tried to pass an empty list to those vars?

Comment: I guess the intention is to have a single statement block for all role identities (if provided) and then another for all services (also if provided) so that would make sense if so but it's hard to tell without the question being expanded.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @ydaetskcoR. Added example of the problem

Comment: @Nick that's the problem that I cannot give empty values. Added example of the problem

Comment: Thanks for updating it with the actual error. That is about to be expected, as the AWS API won't accept an empty Principal in the trust policy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }

  dynamic "statement" {
    for_each     = length(var.assume_role_identities) > 0 ? [var.assume_role_identities] : []
    content {
      actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
      principals {
        type        = "AWS"
        identifiers = var.assume_role_identities
      }
    }
  }

  dynamic "statement" {
    for_each     = length(var.assume_role_services) > 0 ? [var.assume_role_services] : []
    content {
      actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
      principals {
        type        = "Service"
        identifiers = var.assume_role_services
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You don't event need the first statement, you can pass it as an argument to var.assume_role_services